# What is the difference between $and and $all in this particular case?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

These two lines of code simply output the same result, so what is the difference between them? I know I know, documentation... But I mean in this context. Thank you for your answers!

```
db.someData.find({$and: [{genre: {$eq: "action"}}, {genre: {$eq: "thriller"}}]}).pretty()

db.someData.find({genre: {$all: ["action", "thriller"]}}).pretty()
```

This is the collection in my mongodb database.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d19fe6080fc4d046d99d42b"),
        "title" : "The Last Student Returns",
        "meta" : {
                "rating" : 9.5,
                "aired" : 2018,
                "runtime" : 100
        },
        "visitors" : 1300000,
        "expectedVisitors" : 1550000,
        "genre" : [
                "thriller",
                "drama",
                "action"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d19fe6080fc4d046d99d42c"),
        "title" : "Teach me if you can",
        "meta" : {
                "rating" : 8.5,
                "aired" : 2014,
                "runtime" : 90
        },
        "visitors" : 590378,
        "expectedVisitors" : 500000,
        "genre" : [
                "action",
                "thriller"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d19fe6080fc4d046d99d42d"),
        "title" : "Supercharged Teaching",
        "meta" : {
                "rating" : 9.3,
                "aired" : 2016,
                "runtime" : 60
        },
        "visitors" : 370000,
        "expectedVisitors" : 1000000,
        "genre" : [
                "thriller",
                "action"
        ]
}
```

Comment: The first: find ONLY those documents with a genre equal to action AND also equal to thriller. Second: fine ALL documents with genres that include action AND thriller.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Not really. Both queries do the "Second" thing, see Akrion's answer below

Comment: @Thilo - Don't disagree at all - I actually changed my comment from "exactly the same" (unhelpful comment) to the literal _what's the difference_ comment - OP already knows they "produce exactly the same" result.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that you mentioned `documentation` since [your exact question is actually answered there](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/index.html#equivalent-to-and-operation):

**Behavior**

> **Equivalent to $and Operation**
>
> The **$all** is equivalent to an **$and** operation of the specified values;
>   i.e. the following statement:

```
{ tags: { $all: [ "ssl" , "security" ] } }
```

**is equivalent to:**

```
{ $and: [ { tags: "ssl" }, { tags: "security" } ] }
```

But overall there are many ways to get the same result with `mongo` just like there are many ways to get the same exact result with JS etc.